Ultrasonic Piezo Crystal properties, temperature and phase
I have a pulse consisting of sine waves driving a piezo transducer at around 120kHz into a gas.
If the gas temperature remains constant, but the temperature of the piezo changes how will that affect the timing between the input signal and what I measure in the gas?
At the very least the thickness of the crystal changes but I am not sure how that will affect the phase timing of the wave. I am measuring to within 10ns, so it matters

Oh that is an interesting temperature sensor! (if it is a pronounced phase shift, which I think we hope it's not?)

@MarcusMüller At the resolution we are working at, everything is a thermometer

"There's only two types of devices: Thermal sensors, and thermal sensors that you intend for measuring temperature"

but yes, this is essential an characteristic impedance boundary thing, at least that's how I'd probably model it. Hm; wonder how material stiffness of the Piezo is affected thermally. Are there any papers on low-frequency piezo resonant frequencies vs temperature? Feels like something someone has measured

Can you please provide more information on the transducer? For example, do you have a part number or know the material?
